# Bootstrap alignment of button and pagination

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using Twitter Bootstrap 3 to build my new website. I want to place a button on the left side and a pagination on the right side.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Default</button>

<ul class="pagination pull-right">
    <li><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>
 </ul>
```

My problem is that I am unable to align the both elements properly:

http://bootply.com/91723

The pagination has a small offset.

What can i do to remove that offset?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try adding ths:-

```
.pagination {
margin: 0px !important;
}
```

Comment: Yep i guess this is more elegant solution than mine but keep in mind that if you use !important ALL paginations will have margin:0 and maybe you don't want that

Comment: Yes, for that may be we can add an extra class with it...:)

Answer (score 16):

Wrap a semantic descriptive class around your button and pagination, such as .navigation-bar and use this to target the margin on the .pagination:

```
.navigation-bar .pagination {
      margin-top: 0;
    }
```

http://bootply.com/91736

You should never override a framework class directly, as it would apply across your entire code base. The alternative is to simply extend the .pagination class:

```
<ul class="pagination no-margin pull-right">
```

Answer (score 8):

I would go for:

```
<div class="btn-toolbar" role="toolbar" style="margin: 0;">
      <div class="btn-group">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">1</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">2</button>
      </div>

      <div class="btn-group pull-right">
                <ul class="pagination" style="margin: 0;">
                <li><a href="#">«</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">»</a></li>
            </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

http://www.bootply.com/116457

if you replace the `<ul><li....` with buttons , you not need to use `style="margin: 0;`

Example here:
http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups-toolbar

Comment: You can get what you want with standard BS CSS classes. Good tip. Tks.

Answer (score 2):

Put the below styling in the ul element:

```
<ul style="margin-top:0;" class="pagination pull-right">
```

Answer (score 0):

add this class to your ul and in your css:

```
.no-top-margin {
  margin-top: 0;
 }
```

or this to your button and css:

```
.add-top-margin {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

Also I would recommend Googling and reading some beginner tutorials on using either Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug for firefox, especially if you are going to be doing more html/web development in the future :-).

Answer (score 0):

You could set a width and use margins to centre it on the page. Also note for this solution to work you have to remove `.pull-right` from the `ul`

Here is the HTML:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left">Default</button>

            <ul class="pagination pull-right">
                <li><a href="#">«</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">»</a></li>
            </ul>
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.pagination {
  display: block;
  width: 232px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: #ccc;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can put it in a table & then apply margin top.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left">
            Default</button>
    </td>
    <td>
        <ul class="pagination pull-right">
            <li><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>
        </ul>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Holy cow, no. Do not use tables for layout.

Answer (score -1):

```
`<div class="pagination justify-content-center pagination-large" id="pagination-demo">
```

`

justify-content-center will flex your pag to center